# Hibernate : Foreign Key not updated for in-memory object with unidirectional OneToMany Relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have following problem with 2 entities - Request and Participant. Its unidirectional relationship where one request might contain multiple participants.

```
 @Entity
    public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "id_sequence",
            sequenceName = "REQUEST_SEQUENCE",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long id;

    private String requestorFullName;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "requestId")
    private Set<Participant> participants = Sets.newHashSet();

    }
```

---

```
  @Entity
    public class Participant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = 
    "id_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "id_sequence",
            sequenceName = "PARTICIPANT_SEQUENCE",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    private Long id;

    //foreign key-----------
    private Long requestId;

    }
```

I am trying to save a new Request with multiple participants. when I try to save new request instance, foreign key in Participant table is persisted, but the same is not reflected in in-memory object, hence the field 'requestId' is null.

```
Request request ; //contains multiple participants
requestRepository.save(request);
//foreign key is peristed in DB, but 'requestId' in in-memory(now persisted) participants is 
//not updated, whereas both the id fields are updated.
```

Comment: It wont, you have to either reload everyhing from db or update FK yourself.

Comment: am i missing something or hibernate wont populate the foreign key since this is unidirectional relationship ?

Comment: it never sets relations by itself on updates, only when fetching entities. If you query something from the database, you will get nice full entity graph with bi/uni relationships (depends on mapping). If you however change something eg in bi directional relation, you have to update other side of relation by yourself - in your case, you are creating ne w relation. In db it requires only 1 update but here you must set parents children as well as childrens' parent. Updated ID is special case (PK) as entity becomes managed thus it must contain ID. You would have to fetch it again otherwise;)

Comment: But the `request` entity OP is persisting already has associated `participants` filled in.

Answer (score 0):

The `requestId` will not be populated, it is specified as join column in `OneToMany` annotation in `Request` entity. JPA will not treat it like other columns. If you want it's value then use `request::getId`.

Comment: As you mentioned its unlike other columns - exactly my point. Implicitly JPA provider knows that its an foreign key, hence I think it should be populated.

Comment: The column is populated, the entity attribute is not. "Object" world does not require foreign keys to specify relationships, it is how the RDMS works. Using the `@JoinColumn` annotation we inform hibernate how this relationship is orchestrated in db.

Comment: yes I understand what you are saying. I cant understand - why hibernate won't update the foreign key in object, when its already updating the IDs.

Comment: Because the participants objects do not need to know anything about the request objects they are associated with, the table needs the foreign key. Have you tried adding @Column on requestId? Also, don't look at the `Participant` and  `Request` objects as some sophisticated JDBC `ResultSet`.